# Getting error while kubeflow deployment in gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow

I have followed this [doc](https://thechief.io/c/cloudplex/what-kubeflow-and-how-deploy-it-kubernetes/) to deploy kubeflow on gke

> Error:404 page not found

when Accessing Central dashboard

Try to deploy multiple times but still getting same error

I'm new to kubernets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this official [doc](https://v0-5.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/troubleshooting-gke/#404-page-not-found-when-accessing-central-dashboard), try below troubleshooting steps to resolve your error :

> This section provides troubleshooting information for 404s, page not
> found, being return by the central dashboard which is served at
>
> ```
> https://${KUBEFLOW_FQDN}/
> ```
>
> KUBEFLOW_FQDN is your project’s OAuth web app URI domain name
> `<name>.endpoints.<project>.cloud.goog`
>
> We can confirm that the Ambassador reverse proxy is functioning
> properly by running the following command because we were able to sign
> in.
>
> ```
>  kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} get pods -l service=envoy
>     NAME                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
>    envoy-76774f8d5c-lx9bd   2/2       Running   2          4m
>    envoy-76774f8d5c-ngjnr   2/2       Running   2          4m
>    envoy-76774f8d5c-sg555   2/2       Running   2          4m
> ```
>
> Now try to Attempt different administrations to check whether they're
> open for instance
>
> ```
>    https://${KUBEFLOW_FQDN}/whoami
>    https://${KUBEFLOW_FQDN}/tfjobs/ui
>    https://${KUBEFLOW_FQDN}/hub
> ```
>
> We know that the issue is specific to the central dashboard and not
> ingress if other services are accessible.
>
> Now check that the central dashboard is running
>
> ```
> kubectl get pods -l app=centraldashboard
> NAME                                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
> centraldashboard-6665fc46cb-592br   1/1       Running   0          7h
> ```
>
> Check that an Ambassador route is properly defined or not
>
> ```
> kubectl get service centraldashboard -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.getambassador\.io/config}'
>
> apiVersion: ambassador/v0
>   kind:  Mapping
>   name: centralui-mapping
>   prefix: /
>   rewrite: /
>   service: centraldashboard.kubeflow
> ```
>
> ,
>
> Take a look at the logs of Envoy for blunders. Check to see if there
> are any errors like these that indicate a problem parsing the route.
> In the event that you are utilizing the new Stackdriver Kubernetes
> observing you can utilize the accompanying channel in the stackdriver
> console
>
> ```
>  resource.type="k8s_container"
>  resource.labels.location=${ZONE}
>  resource.labels.cluster_name=${CLUSTER}
>  metadata.userLabels.service="ambassador"
> "could not parse YAML"
> ```

You can also refer to this [doc](https://v1-5-branch.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/) for more information aboutdeploying kubeflow on GKE.